# На WordPress-сайте возникла ошибка при смене темы

Tags: wordpress

Когда пытаюсь поменять тему, пишет это

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\widgets.php:1265 Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\widgets.php(1265): array_merge(wp_inactive_widgets: Array, sidebar-1: Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\widgets.php(1220): retrieve_widgets(true)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(289): _wp_sidebars_changed('Twenty Twenty')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\theme.php(3267): do_action('after_switch_th...', 'Twenty Twenty', Object(WP_Theme))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): check_theme_switched('')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-settings.php(546): do_action('init')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-config.php(89): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-admin\themes.php(10): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#14 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress.dev\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 1265
На сайте возникла критическая ошибка. Пожалуйста, проверьте входящие сообщения почты администратора для дальнейших инструкций.
```

Comment: какая версия php у вас?

Comment: @Seredniy это автор из серии "выстрелил вопросом и забыл"

Comment: Новая, 8.0 версия

Comment: @MaksimAliev WordPress не совместим пока с php8. Первая совместимая версия - WP 5.6, выйдет 8 декабря. Но многие плагины обновятся ещё позже.

Comment: окей, спасибо большое) сорян за долгий ответ